# regex search using string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string of text that has the value of the selected text. Id like to do a replace() of this text in a given div of text.

so I know I can do that with the following:

`myelement.replace(/foo/g, 'bar');`

However I need to do it with my string ie:

`myelement.replace(/*mystring*/g, 'bar');`

So I tried:

```
mystring = '/'+mystring+'/g';
myelement.replace(mystring, 'bar');
```

Which didnt work, so i tried (which i knew wouldn't work):

`myelement.replace(/+mystring+/g, 'bar');`

So how can i do this?

I've coded something up for you guys in jsfiddle --> [HELP ME PLEASE!](http://jsfiddle.net/5DYZN/)

Comment: Btw, `$('#myelement')` will return a jQuery object, not a string. If you want to replace the content of the element, have a look at the `.html()` and `.text()` methods: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: You need to create a `new RegExp()`

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks mate. I missed typed this in the question (now ammended). It was correct in the jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2rG2V/

The change being to use `new RegExp(st, "g")` instead of creating the string as you did before. `/test/g` is just a shortcut way of creating a RegExp object.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I check [another answer]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript that @Felix Kling alerted me to. So i will accept your answer when I can. Big thanks to Felix too.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed that Felix had pointed out a dupe when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply replace your

```
regSt = '/'+st+'/g';
```

with

```
regSt = new RegExp(st,'g');
```

more info on regExp http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('myelement.replace(/' + mystring + '/g, "bar");');
```

Comment: Ugh! `eval()`? Isn't this like that forbidden apple?